# Do I need to upgrade to the newest version of Go?

Tags: go

I use go1.14.11 in my product environment, it works fine until now.
But there have been so many versions after 1.14.11, most of them have some security fixes.

I wonder if I need to upgrade to the newest version of Go? Is there any big problem if I keep with go1.14.11?

Comment: Yes, upgrade. There is no point in using outdated, unmaintained, old and buggy versions of the compiler or stdlib.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any big problem if I keep with go1.14.11?

Yes. The Go team maintains and releases security updates for the 2 latest major versions, which currently are 1.16 and 1.15. There are no updates to 1.14 released anymore.

This means if you've built your app using Go 1.14 and a security bug is discovered in its code, your app will be vulnerable to it. You can only get protection for those newly discovered bugs if they get fixed in the Go SDK and you rebuild your app with a version that contains that fix. And as mentioned above, that can only be any of the supported version, that is, any of Go 1.16 or 1.15.

Beyond the security fixes, newer versions of Go tend to be faster. So using newer versions you often get better performance (faster apps) just by using them, without improving / optimizing anything in your app. There is no reason not to use the latest version available at any time.

Comment: Worth noting about the "security updates" point, even if you use a supported version, you'll never get security updates if you never actually update. For example, OP is missing a security update from 1.14.12, which came out half a year ago.

Answer (score 5):

[The Go team supports the last two major versions.](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Go-Release-Cycle#release-maintenance) At the time of writing those are 1.16 and 1.15.

This means 1.14 does not receive security patches anymore and you should upgrade. Note that Go has a very strict backward compatibility policy, so upgrading is easy.